# Copy vs photocopy difference?

Tags: difference

IS there any difference between *copy* and *photocopy* of original document?

I need to make 1 original copy and 3 photocopies but I don't know is there any difference between them. Could you explain me?

Comment: Probably not in 'I need to make a copy'. But 'can I copy your homework' means can I use what you've done to write out mine? (i.e. not photocopy)

Comment: There are numerous ways of making a copy, one of which is to photocopy. See: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/copy. What is meant by one original copy is not clear, unless this copy was to be in some way notarised or authorised.

Comment: There little logic to that but my guess is that 1 original copy is to be printed from the original file and 3 photocopies are to be made using a photocopier. Could you give some more context as to what document is that, whether it is in color or in shades of gray?

Comment: @RonaldSole The word _copy_ is sometimes used (as a noun) to refer to a particular instance of a document that there are multiple copies of (See noun definition B2 [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/copy)). It therefore _can_ make sense to say "original copy" to mean the document from which the photocopies were produced (although it's probably more common to just use "original", without adding "copy").

Comment: *photocopy* was more commonly used before modern scanners became available. If I recall correctly, they took a photo of the page to make the copy.

Answer (score 3):

A *photocopy* is specifically the product/result of scanning a piece of paper on a copy machine or printer.

A *copy* can mean this if context strongly suggests, but can mean different things.  For example, you can copying files on your computer's desktop, but those aren't photocopies (even if you print them).

*Original copy* would refer to the document you are scanning on the copy machine/printer.  This is common with documents that originated purely electronically (like Word documents) and are only just now getting around to being on paper for the first time.

If you have to make this original copy, it probably means you have to print it from the computer and retain this copy for your own records - also implying the other photocopies will be sent out and not retained.

Answer (score 1):

> IS there any difference between copy and photocopy of original document

**Copy** can be a difficult word to pin down as to meaning in English.
The Latin word from which the English **Copy** derives, *copia* means "a lot of", a great quantity", or "an abundance" [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/copy).
 *Copia* came to mean "transcript" [Ibid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/copy) (something written from something else) [Cambridge Dictionary online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/transcript). That was by reducing **copy** (copia) to use as a singular to provide a word for one of an abundance.

**Photocopy** is much easier to define. There is the term **copy** in the definition *A thing made to be similar or identical to another.* [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/copy) with **photo** accomplished by photographic means. [Merriam Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photocopy)

The issue in the question is what **copy** means. It might mean one of several printed, or otherwise reproduced, instances of the document that originated as a printing, or reproduction, or, the first, or only, instance of a document; both could be an original **copy**.

> 1 original copy

does not really describe what is required.
I believe it would be best for you to inquire of the person giving the instructions as to what  "1 original copy " means in this context.